# Why CSS font-face can not render some fonts properly?

Tags: css, fonts, import, font-face

I want to import 3 fonts in my web page using @font-face. But just one of them renders properly. Others can not be shown as they must appear. Why ?
This is my sample codes to import each item and use it:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'BMitra';
  src: url('fonts/BMitra.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),  
       url('fonts/BMitra.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('fonts/BMitra.ttf') format('truetype');
}
.my_div {
  font-family: 'BMitra';
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Actually I think CSS can find the fonts, but it can not show them as their real appearance.

This is what I'm seeing now:
[image]
And this is what I have to see as the real appearance (I'm loading this font locally):
[image]

Comment: Your code example only shows one font being imported. You need to show all three fonts being imported.

Comment: @Setek I mentioned this is a sample to show how I imported each font. Actually I imported 3 fonts.

Comment: Are you getting issues in particular browsers, or all? Do you have a public page we can see the issue?

Comment: In all browsers. It is not on the Internet

Answer (score 0):

Font-face is to something which is depend on user's system as well as rendering client..
The browser isn't going to wait to download the fonts first before loading the rest of your style sheet.

**Please refer these links -**

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/11/troubleshooting-font-face-problems

You can use some **css tricks or hacks**

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

The @font-face rule is supported  by all the major browsers in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

However, Internet Explorer 9 only supports .eot type fonts, while Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera support .ttf and .otf type fonts.

**Note:-** Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the @font-face rule.
But there are lot of rules,tricks and hack present to make it working in all the legacy browsers also..

Please refer above mentioned links for more reference.

**Suggestion :-** As a User Interface Analyst  I would suggest to also use font which is globally recommended (Having support in all the browsers). If you have these requirement so try to find some alternative for that.

***Thanks !!***

Answer (score 0):

I could found the cause of problem.
The fonts files I was copied to my project had 2 versions (There was 2 files for a same font). One for **normal weight**, and another one for **bold weight**. I was copied normal files only, whereas I wanted to show them in bold appearance.

My fonts directory:
[image]

Different versions of a same font:
[image]

I replaced files and the problem solved.
Thank you all for your attentions to my problem.